# Maven cannot resolve package from another module dependency

Tags: java, maven, module

I have a multi-module Maven project structure with several layers, something like this:

```
root-module
    module-group
        war-module
            pom.xml
        jar-module1
            pom.xml
        jar-module2
            pom.xml
        pom.xml
    another-module
        pom.xml
    etc
        pom.xml
pom.xml
```

`module-group`, `another-module` and `etc` have `root-module` as their parent.

So `root-module/pom.xml` has this:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>module-group</module>
    <module>another-module</module>
    <module>etc</module>
</modules>
```

and each of those modules has this:

```
<parent>
    <!-- artifact coordinates etc -->
    <artifactId>root-module</artifactId>
</parent>
```

Then, `war-module`, `jar-module1` and `jar-module2` have `module-group` as their parent. Thus, `module-group/pom.xml` also includes:

```
<modules>
    <module>war-module</module>
    <module>jar-module1</module>
    <module>jar-module2</module>
</modules>
```

`war-module` has `jar-module1` in its `<dependecies>`, and `jar-module1` depends on `jar-module2`. War-module has `<packaging>war</packaging>`, `jar-*` modules have `jar`.

So dependency chain is like `war-module -> jar-module1 -> jar-module2`. Versions for each artifact are defined using `${revision}` (I'm using Maven3).

I was trying to introduce the dependency chain from `war-module` in the profiles in `war-module/pom.xml`:

```
<profiles>
    <!-- this profile is for building with jar-module1 (jar-module2 is resolved transitively) -->
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>jar-module1</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <!-- this profile is for building without jar-module1 (straight dependency to jar-module2) -->
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>jar-module2</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

However, when I try to build my project (or just `module-group` or even `jar-module1`) the process exits with error while packaging `jar-module1`:

```
package org.example.package.from.jarmodule2 doesn't exist.
```

(that package has the only Java class from `jar-module2` referenced in `jar-module1`). However, I have the `target` folder in my `jar-module2` with correct `.jar` in it. IntelliJ IDEA resolves the classes correctly, only Maven cannot build it right. What might be the problem?
Also, if I introduce the dependency without using profiles, it seems to package correctly. But I need to build different configurations all the time and would really love to not have to change `pom.xml` every time.

Comment: Which maven version exactly? From where do you build? From `root-module` via `mvn package`?

Comment: So it seems the problem is connected to the fact that I was trying to introduce the dependencies `jar-module1` and `jar-module2` in the profiles. E.g. I was trying to have 2 profiles: 1) `war-module` -> `jar-module1` -> `jar-module2` and 2) `war-module` -> `jar-module2`. So that I could build different module configurations... Changed to the normal dependency node and it works now

Comment: Remove profiles with dependencies that's wrong. Please make an example project on github.

Comment: I need different module configurations for different needs (some modules need to be included, some not in different situations). I seem to have fixed it with using a property inside a dependency.